# Unresolved reference on valid function name - Python

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python, but despite having experience with other languages its syntax seems to trip me up more than it should.

In the below code I have an unresolved reference on the call to `autoclick` within the for loop, and I'm not sure why. I think it might be something to do with my parameters as when I call `single_click()` and `double_click()` there's no error.

```
minDelayMs = int(input("Minimum delay between clicks (ms)?"))
maxDelayMs = int(input("Maximum delay between clicks (ms)?"))
clickType = input("1 or 2 clicks?")
numClicks = input("Number of clicks?")

minDelaySec = minDelayMs / 1000
maxDelaySec = maxDelayMs / 1000

print("Min delay (seconds): " + str(minDelaySec))
print("Max delay (seconds): " + str(maxDelaySec))

totalTime = 0
totalClicks = 0

print("10 second delay until start...")
time.sleep(10)
print("Starting")

for x in range(int(numClicks)):
    auto_click(minDelayMs, minDelayMs, clickType)


def auto_click(minDelayMs, maxDelayMs, clickType):
    global totalTime
    global totalClicks

    #get next delay in ms
    delay = random.randint(minDelayMs, maxDelayMs)
    totalTime = totalTime + delay
    print("Next delay in ms: " + str(delay))

    # sleep for the delay in sec
    time.sleep(delay/1000)

    if(clickType == 1):
        single_click()

    if(clickType == 2):
        double_click()

    totalClicks += 1
    clicksRemaining = int(numClicks) - totalClicks
    print("Clicks remaining: " + str(clicksRemaining) + "\n")
    return


def single_click():
    mouse.press(Button.left)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    mouse.release(Button.left)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Click cycle")
    return


def double_click():
    mouse.press(Button.left)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    mouse.release(Button.left)
    print("Click cycle")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    mouse.press(Button.left)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    mouse.release(Button.left)
    print("Click cycle")
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be declared before using it. And you use it in global `for`-loop, which is being executed at the global scope, that means immediately.

Comment: Interpreted vs compiled. I completely forget sometimes.

Comment: The issue is more one of allowing top-level code that isn't a function definition. Python *is* compiled (to byte code, which is then interpreted by a virtual machine), but Python also allows top-level code that isn't itself a function definition, allowing you to reference functions before they have been defined (rather than referencing them after `main` has been called, which happens after everything has been compiled).